# I run nanogpt on pytorch 1.10.0，but error,AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'amp'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

i run train.py on ubuntu 20.04,gpu 2080ti or 3060,but
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'amp'

pytorch 1.10.0,
python 3.8
ubuntu 20.04
cuda 11.3

this error i don't know why.

i change torch version it didn't work

cuda version and gpu i all try

Comment: Your PyTorch version is probably too old

Answer (score 0):

You could change it to torch.autocast(...) instead of torch.amp.autocast(...)

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html

Comment: Thank you,i know why,this is Pytorch version problem.